# Amazon AWS hosted nodeJs project not accessible

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-web-services

Hosting NodeJs on Amazon AWS EC2. Server running there as shown in command line as Server running at: http://ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:3456. But when i'm trying to open it in browser i cant access it using "DNS Hostname:Port Number".

Example : http://ec2-52-0-14-185.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/**(Not my link)**

**P.S.** I'm from **India** and Server is hosted at **US West(Oregon)**.

Comment: What you have in your shell?

Answer (score 1):

Did you open the port for the server? If not, check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)). You should open the port which your node.js application is listening to.

Comment: I opened all traffic but still my website is inaccessible. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779478/nodejs-website-hosted-on-aws-linux-is-not-accessible