# NodeJs website hosted on AWS linux is not accessible

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I hosted my NodeJs website on AWS Red Hat Linux but it's accessible from outside.
although when i run my nodejs server from putty, it was running just fine.
[image]

below is my server creation code in nodejs.I'm using express framework with jade.

```
app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Server starts on port: ' + 80);
});
```

I have opened all traffic from AWS console also and tried other ports as well.

```
ps -ef | grep node says:-
```

[image]

and app.log says:-

```
uncaughtException: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
Server starts on port: 80
```

Comment: `ps -ef | grep node` ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma: added it's output in the question now.

Comment: As cleared from the screenshot. Your `node` process is not running. I think once you close the shell, your node process shut down. Try `nohup node app.js &`

Comment: ok, now it's running. please check updated screenshot in the question.

Comment: You missed `&` , Add that too, to run in background.

Comment: please check updated screenshot. still now working for me. please bear with me, I'm new to linux. @MukeshSharma

Comment: Sure :) This should work `nohup node app.js >> app.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &`

Comment: please check updated screenshot. @MukeshSharma

Comment: Now, it should work. `ps -ef | grep node` should show `node` process, and `tail -f app.log` should show logs.

Comment: app log was saying:- uncaughtException: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
now check your last reply.

Comment: `kill -9 16024` and `kill -9 16027`, then `nohup node app.js >> app.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &` should run the app perfectly.

Comment: please check updated screenshot. server runs on port 80 but site is not accessible.

Comment: @MukeshSharma: What could be the issue?

Comment: Try running your node server with "sudo". If that doesn't work, I would follow this: https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/776580

Comment: it says:- Error: listen EADDRINUSE @MatthewBordas. I think server is already running.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi so if the server is running but the site is not accessible then you probably just need to change the port settings for the instance on the AWS dashboard so that the server can accept incoming connections on port 80 from the outside world

Comment: I already opened all ports but still same issue. please check 2nd screenshot in the question. @MatthewBordas

Comment: Can you send us a screenshot of your instances port settings on the aws dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as there is already a application that is using `port 80` on your system, probably `Apache` or `Nginx`, so you should just use another port and configure your web-server to forward all `HTTP` requests to your port or just stop the webserver, also to use port 80 you need to use `sudo` so your commmand will be `sudo node app.js`. If you want to check what application is running on `port 80` just use following commmand :

```
sudo netstat -tupln | grep 80
```

the output should show you what process is using your port you can kill it if you want

Comment: not working, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926433/aws-linux-ubuntu-hosted-application-is-not-accessible-from-public-ip

Comment: the question you are pointing to is different as in it you ask that it is not accessible. Here you asked why are you getting this error **uncaughtException: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
Server starts on port: 80**

Answer (score 0):

```
app.listen(80,"0.0.0.0", function () {
console.log('Server starts on port: ' + 80);
});``
```

it should work always make sure your app is accessible over the network eg "0.0.0.0" parameter`enter code here`

Comment: not working. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926433/aws-linux-ubuntu-hosted-application-is-not-accessible-from-public-ip