# AWS Linux (Ubuntu) hosted application is not accessible from public ip

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I hosted a nodejs(express hello world app) application on AWS Linux(Ubuntu 16.04) on free-tier. When i do `wget http://localhost:8080` it runs successfully and saved the output in index.html file.
But when i do the same thing with the public ip (`wget http://35.154.40.189:8080`) of my instance, it says

`Connecting to 35.154.40.189:8080... failed: No route to host.`

I also used the steps given in http://www.lauradhamilton.com/how-to-set-up-a-nodejs-web-server-on-amazon-ec2 to forward all ipv4 traffic to my application but it doesn't work.

I also enabled port 8080 from aws console.
[image]

```
netstat -atn says
```

[image]

```
netstate -ntlp says
```

[image]

I tried everything which i get on internet but unable to resolve the issue. Now i'm too much frustrated. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost

Comment: did u enable all tcp/ip for all public request in your security group?

Comment: @Rogier: added screenshot for netstate -ntlp in the question.

Comment: @Adil: added screenshot of security group in question.

Comment: is your node running with background like we do with nohup node index.js

Comment: one more thing... if your appache is also running then try to change the port dear and every instance have two ip private and public try to access with public

Comment: yes, it's running, although i used pm2 for that. @Adil

Comment: No, I have not installed anything other than node. I have created new aws instance to host node js application only. @Adil

Comment: my node application also running in AWS but the link you follow its has lot change

Comment: @JitendraPancholi why is it port 22 (ssh) is missing? You do have access, so any change you the group is not associated with the instance?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxhFq64FQzA&t=1693s

Comment: dear @JitendraPancholi watch this video you will get every thing if its first time with node and AWS its cover every thing when i was setup all these setup

Comment: thanks a lot @Adil I will watch this now.

Comment: you always welcome dear @JitendraPancholi

Comment: @Adil: Thanks man, you saved my life. :) I was installing node by command earlier which was creating some configuration issue.

Comment: you can post your solution and I will make that as answer.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi : You can try by Just uploading .zip file to aws ec2. after sign in to aws click this link https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=us-east-1#/applications

Comment: @JitendraPancholi thats glad to me dear ...okay let me post bro:)

Comment: @JitendraPancholi So after just reinstalling node.js it worked? without you making any code change?

Comment: @AJS: It worked without making any change in code. I just reinstalled nodejs as said by Adil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- MAke Your Instance in AWS first
- Enable inbound rule as u mention in picutre
- Enable user group after ssh connection with AWS ubuntu instance
- once instance start running then **Install node properly**
- `sudu apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev g++ make`
- download source code of node from web `node.tar.gz` wih command `wget link`
  https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.1/node-v6.9.1.tar.gz
- `tar -xvf node -v0.10.32.tar.gz`
- now goto node  after unzip .gz
- `./configure && make && sudo make && sudo make install`

boom your node server is ready on new AWS instances

or watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxhFq64FQzA&t=1693s

Comment: Thanks a lot Adil. Earlier i was installing the node js by Ubuntu Package Manager "sudo apt-get install nodejs" which was the issue.

Comment: Hey, I installed pm2 and npmbox on the server and now I can not access the application from outside.

Comment: netstat -atn says tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: i think something messed up in iptables.

Comment: change the listening port or let me know further

Comment: i did it but no luck.